# float output left in CDF

Tags: alignment

I'm experimenting with embedding a CDF on a Wordpress site and while it mostly works, the plots are running out of room along the right edge.

It seems like if the images were floated left they would fit and look like the output does in MMA.

This might have a simple answer, yet how to force the plot output to float left?

See http://nomtbf.com/2013/04/weibull-vs-exponential-pdfs/

for an example of the issue.

Comment: Maybe you could just specify another `PlotRange` such that the x-axis goes up to 300 or so?

Answer (score 1):

`ContentSize` changes the size of the elements in the Manipulate field, and `ImageSize` changes the size of the field itself. It would probably be worth trying both in this case.

Comment: Thanks that did the trick - there is a way to adjust anything if you know the command... thanks!